# Ubuntu MATE 16.04 Bluetooth sudden failure

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, mate, wii

This is really weird. yesterday, I was using my Nintendo Wiimotes to play a game with dolphin emulator. Today, I turned on my computer, and when I turned on Bluetooth, it said that I didn't have any adapter. I rebooted my computer, but it still said that, and I couldn't see anything from the bluesman manager. I reinstalled everything and then later rebuilt the driver from the latest backports, but it still didn't work. I then booted into an earlier kernel that I was sure worked, and sure enough, it still doesn't work. I don't know what to do, this is ridiculous being that this whole system was working fine for months now. Please let me know what I should do, its really bugging me. Thanks!

```
matanya@matanya-ThinkPad-P50s:~$ lspci -knn | grep -i -A3 "wireless\|bluetooth\|network"
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:1130]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
06:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM108GLM [Quadro K620M] [10de:137a] (rev a2)


matanya@matanya-ThinkPad-P50s:~$ rfkill list
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your question by adding output of `lspci -knn | grep -i -A3 "wireless\|bluetooth\|network"`.

Also please add output of `rfkill list`.

If it shows `Soft blocked: yes` or `Hard blocked: yes` - try to unblock devices with `rfkill unblock all`.

Try to run *Bluetooth Manager* from System->Preferences->Hardware* (or `blueman-manager` command) and check adapter from *Adapter->Preferences*.

Also you can try to search around devices with *Search* button.